# Access a subversion repository on a Windows share from Linux

Tags: windows, subversion, cifs

For a long time we put SVN repositories on a Windows share (worked great as only one person was working on one project).

Now, we are moving dev machines away from Windows to Ubuntu and we need to access those repositories from Ubuntu.

I mounted the svn repositories share like this:

```
//win_serv/svn /mnt/svn cifs credentials=/home/u/.smbcreds,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

I managed to change repository URL to `/mnt/svn/some_project`. However, trying to do `svn up` causes an error:

```
svn: E200033: Another process is blocking the working copy database, or the underlying filesystem does not support file locking; if the working copy is on a network filesystem, make sure file locking has been enabled on the file server
svn: E200033: sqlite[S5]: database is locked
svn: E200033: Additional errors:
svn: E200033: sqlite[S5]: database is locked
```

Am I doing something wrong (besides the 'svn repository on windows share' fact)?

Is it even possible to access an svn repo on a Windows share from Linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would encourage you not to do this. Either host a SVN server on Windows or on Linux and access the server using svn+ssh protocol. Do not try and develop some kludged method for accessing your SVN repositories.

There are a number of issues you're going to run into that are SVN and SQLite related that you'll run into that require various mounting options such as NOBRL to CIFS.

I'd really encourage you to avoid all this and decide upfront where you want the SVN repositories to reside, and then invest the time in setting up an actual SVN sever on that system vs. proceeding down the path that you're already trying.

Also invest some time in researching the various  setup options in the [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/), it's free, and spells out the best ways to do what you're doing so you don't destroy or jeopardize losing your data.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with what slm has said - do not do that, SVN was built so that you do not have to share file systems - you can try to avoid such problems with the mount option `nobrl`. See [the Samba manpages](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/3.5/man-html/mount.cifs.8.html) for more information about the mount option.

Comment: This helped me do a commit from a temporarily mounted CIFS working copy (on a web server) where I was setting uid,gid.